# Ajax web-service

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I have many problems with my ajax request. I test the web-service manually and works fine but my jquery ajax request show the next error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.newvision.pt/InlineDisplays/Displays.asmx/GetTicketsXMLDebug?&DisplayIds=1|2. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

My ajax request is:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "xml",
        url: "http://www.newvision.pt/InlineDisplays/Displays.asmx/GetTicketsXMLDebug?&DisplayIds=1|2" ,
        crossDomain: true,
        // jsonp: false,
        // processData: false,
        success: function(data){

            console.log(data);

        },
        error: function(objeto, quepaso, otroobj){
            console.log(this.url);
            console.log("ERROR");
        }
    });
```

If someone knows what is the problem i would apreciatte it!!!
Thx!!!

Comment: 'Same-domain' restriction strikes again: you cannot just AJAXload some resource that doesn't belong to you (i.e., lies not at the same domain as your own site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the age old problem off cross domain request do a simple google search for cross domain requests and you will see millions off results. You cannot ajax a request from one domain to another for security reasons.

There are some possibilities using jsonP format again a quick search should help you with that.

Comment: Thxx but with jsonP i could parse a xml response?